# Custom methods of Web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

It is possible to define custom functions on custom elements?

Something like:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.customMethod = function () { ... };

document.registerElement('custom-el', {
  prototype: proto
});
```

And calling the method on the element:

```
var istance = document.createElement('custom-el');
instance.customMethod();
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, of course.

Your example works as you can see in the code snippet below:

**New answer for Custom Elements v1**

```js
class CE extends HTMLElement {
  customMethod() {
    console.log( 'customMethod called' )
  }
}

customElements.define( 'custom-el', CE )

var instance = document.createElement( 'custom-el' )
instance.customMethod()
```

**Old answer for Custom Elements v0 (deprecated)**

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.customMethod = function() {
  console.log('customMethod called')
};

document.registerElement('custom-el', {
  prototype: proto
});
var instance = document.createElement('custom-el');
instance.customMethod();
```

Comment: @Mariusz yes it was working for Custom Elements v0 but now they are deprecated... I updated the code.

Comment: In the same way that custom elements are required to use a hyphen in their name to prevent future namespace collisions with newly created "official" elements, is there no naming standard or some sort of key to place the methods under to prevent name collisions with extensions to the Element API? They didn't think about that or didn't care?